Change prototype chain in multiple level class inheritance
Since JS doesn't allow to extends more than one class, we could be with a complex inheritance chain like this
class Level1 {
    constructor() {
        this.level = 1;
    }

    method1() {
        console.log('This is method 1');
    }
}

class Level2 extends Level1 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 2;
    }

    method2() {
        console.log('This is method 2');
    }
}

class Level3 extends Level2 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 3;
    }

    method3() {
        console.log('This is method 3');
    }
}

class Level4 extends Level3 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 4;
    }

    method4() {
        console.log('This is method 4');
    }
}

class Level5 extends Level4 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 5;
    }

    method5() {
        console.log('This is method 5');
    }
}

let obj = new Level5();
obj.method1(); // Outputs: This is method 1
obj.method2(); // Outputs: This is method 2
obj.method3(); // Outputs: This is method 3
obj.method4(); // Outputs: This is method 4
obj.method5(); // Outputs: This is method 5

Yeah, yeah, I know, you could put all this in on single class, but let just keep it simple.
What would be the best way to create a object that has all methods but from the Level1 class?
Would I have to create another chain like Level2WithouLevel1 -> Level3WithLevel2WithouLeve1...?

What's the use case? There is no simple way to exempt a piece from an existing Prototype chain.

in such cases it's better to use "mixins" in practice if you want to have a compact solution and especially when all your classes are basically independent features. If talking about classes then yes, you will have to do a separate classes chain of inheritance

@connexo there is no use case in mind... I was reading about inheritance, and just thought on this situation... sorry not help

@DanyloGudz Mixins generally require multiple inheritance, which doesn't exist in JS.

What the OP has discovered is a reason why many languages have multiple inheritance, it allows you to mix and match like that. With single inheritance, all you can do is override all the Level1 methods in your subclass.

@DanyloGudz this is a new word for me... I will look for it.

But this is likely to be a design problem. Code in Level2 may depend on methods from Level1. If you then create a child of Level2 that doesn't have these methods, they'll get errors.

@DaniloMourelle Usually you'd just create a new Level5() and not care whether it has methods from Level1 that you may not need. So there is no problem that needs solving here.

@Bergi, I don't know... imagine this method make no sense to be part of this new type o objet... yes, if you don't call it, it wouldn't be a problem, but it will still there... I know this is a rare condition, but i was wondering the solution

@DaniloMourelle If it doesn't make sense, then there's something wrong with the inheritance hierarchy of Level5 in the first place.

@Bergi can't desagree... but let's say you notice this a little too late... there is a way to treat this or would recommend a full refactor?

you could come onto the stackoverflow javascript chat room and i'll try to suggest something for you, i dont really understand what you want to do https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Might worth a read: Composition over inheritance.

Even some built-ins have this exact problem. Take a look at the infamous "god-class" HTMLInputElement, pushing e.g. a checked property on each an any input.

@Barmar How do mixins require poly inheritance? Mixins afaik is more of a concept than a language feature. Any function that accepts an object as a param and "enhances" it by attaching stuff to it to me is a mixin.

Would it be OK to define these five classes as not subclasses, and then use a mixin function to combine the classes that you really want to mix?

@connexo It requires it if you're implementing it at the class level, rather than per-instance.

@trincot I had never heard about mixin before today... I will look more about this

One thing to consider here, is maybe you don't need classes at all. if you're not making use of instanceof and polymorphism, maybe plain functions (and/or objects containing functions) is fine.

@Barmar Since functions are first class members in JS, that's not true. Nothing stops you from passing the class itself to a mixin function. In fact, doing exactly that is how you'd implement mixins to apply composition over inheritance in JS.

@connexo I think I'd need to see an example to understand it.

@Barmar Object.defineProperties(clazz.prototype, props),  is such an example in the only answer given.

@connexo Although if you add new methods to the mixin after that, they won't be picked up. But adding methods dynamically is an unusual operation and doesn't fit all OO paradigms.

@Barmar Make yourself familiar with Javascript's prototypal inheritance. Any method you add to a prototype is available immediately to any object inheriting this prototype. And it's not unusual at all in JavaScript, it's one of the core concepts of the language. Class based inheritance as in Java, C++ or C# is not the end all be all of OOP.

@connexo I'm very familiar with it. But when you use defineProperties you just copy the properties at that time, not new properties that get added to props later.

And that is totally intentional... What are we talking about? That is exactly how a mixin is supposed to work.


As mentioned in comments you cannot remove Level1 from the chain since the child classes could depend on it. But you can easily copy class methods into another class prototype (mix in), note that super isn't supported that way (in the code snippet).

To call a constructor we should extract it from the class source and using new Function call it.

A more tricky approach would be to eval() a whole new class hierarchy based on class list (Level1.toString(), etc)




class Level1 {
    method1() {
        console.log('This is method 1');
    }
}

class Level2 {
    constructor() {
        this.level = 2;
    }

    method2() {
        console.log('This is method 2');
    }
}

class Level3 extends Level2 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 3;
    }

    method3() {
        console.log('This is method 3');
    }
}

class Level4 extends Level3 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 4;
    }

    method4() {
        console.log('This is method 4');
    }
}

class Level5 extends Level4 {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.level = 5;
    }

    method5() {
        console.log('This is method 5');
    }
}

const props = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Level1.prototype);
delete props.constructor;
Object.defineProperties(Level5.prototype, props);

let obj = new Level5();

obj.method1(); // Outputs: This is method 1
obj.method2(); // Outputs: This is method 2
obj.method3(); // Outputs: This is method 3
obj.method4(); // Outputs: This is method 4
obj.method5(); // Outputs: This is method 5

//extend again from Level4 without Leve1l if you need a class without Level1




You might be looking for the mixin pattern. Applied to your case that would mean your LevelX classes do not inherit anymore from each other, but are stand-alone classes that can be mixed/combined to derive a new class that inherits the methods and instance properties of the selected LevelX classes.
If that would answer your needs, then remove the extends clauses and the super() calls from your LevelX classes and define a factory function that creates a dynamic class from a given list of LevelX classes:


function mix(...mixins) {
    const result = class {
        constructor() {
            // Call all the constructors (assuming no arguments)
            Object.assign(this, ...mixins.map(Mixin => new Mixin));
        }
    };
    // Combine the prototypes
    for (const mixin of mixins) {
        Object.defineProperties(result.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(mixin.prototype));
    }
    return result;
}

class Level1 {
    constructor() { this.level = 1; }
    method1() { console.log('This is method 1'); }
}

class Level2 {
    constructor() { this.level = 2; this.level2 = 21; }
    method2() { console.log('This is method 2'); }
}

class Level3 {
    constructor() { this.level = 3; }
    method3() { console.log('This is method 3'); }
}

class Level4 {
    constructor() { this.level = 4; }
    method4() { console.log('This is method 4'); }
}

class Level5 {
    constructor() { this.level = 5; }
    method5() { console.log('This is method 5'); }
}

// Dynamically build a class from given mixins
const Level2345 = mix(Level2, Level3, Level4, Level5);

const obj = new Level2345;
console.log(obj); // { level: 5 }
obj.method2(); // This is method 2
obj.method3(); // This is method 3
obj.method4(); // This is method 4
obj.method5(); // This is method 5
try { obj.method1() }
catch { console.log("method1 is not defined") }




imho this approach is useless in the es6 classes realm, since you cannot call  constructors of mixed in classes, for example change this.level2 = 2 in Level2 and it's undefined in the instance. To use this pattern fully the old function should be used as a constructor I believe.

@AlexanderNenashev, I added this.level2 = 21 in the constructor of Level2 in my snippet, and I see no problem. What are you referring to?

oops, mistaken...

we just need to remember restrictions like no ability to use super

There still is ability to use super in some ways. For instance, you can do Level4 extends SuperLevel4, and have the constructor of SuperLevel4  set yet another property on this; it will work. Sure there are many limitations, but don't exaggerate them ;-)
